# TFS 2015 Installing Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to install tfs server 2015

OS - Server 2012
SQL - SQL server 2012 EXPRESS

There is an error

> TF401159: The SQL Server instance you specified (server\SqlExpress) is
>   version 11.0.2100.60, which cannot be used in place or upgraded. For
>   more information about supported versions of SQL Server, visit
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd578592(v=vs.120).aspx

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SP1 installed for SQL Express?

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Comment: Thanks for your replay , Is it possible to install SP1 with sql server 2012 same sqlexpress

Comment: The second link is for SP1 on Sql Express.